# When using Mathematica Online, where are exported files saved?

Tags: graphics3d, export

I would like to 3D print some Mathematica-generated polyhedra, but I can't figure out how to download the files generated from the 'Export' command. For example:

```
Export["myTestModel.stl", PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"]
```

gives as output

```
myTestModel.stl
```

Which looks like a success! However... the result file is not visible in my "Cloud Files" directory. Where does Mathematica Online store exported files?

Comment: Use `CloudExport`. `Export` doesn't work. I too found this out the hard way, and for the life of me I cannot understand this "design" decision.

Comment: The `Directory[]` command returns the current default directory for files, including `Import[]` and `Export[]` and `FileNames[]` returns a list of filenames in the default directory.

Comment: Apparently `Directory[]` shows the files in the actual Linux server the Wolfram Cloud is built on top of, which somehow slightly differs from the actual cloud file directory (I noticed there wasn't a 1:1 match with files). It's awfully confusing. I'm also not sure how secure things are there, and how much access someone has on the server itself if they're particularly creative.

Comment: The file commands are designed for working on a personal computer and have been in Mathematica for a long time. The cloud commands are relatively new and specifically designed to work with objects in the "cloud". No direct connection between the two functionalities.

Answer (score 10):

After you run the Export command, on the next line type:

```
ExpandFileName["myTestModel.stl"]
```

The output will show you the full path filename.